# I can't able to center the image, what is preventing it centering?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, centering

**I am running the following code, It seems to center in mobile view, but not in Desktop why ? and solution ?**

I tried to solve it by using `display: block; margin: auto; width:100%;` and no use it remains the same. also tried `text-align: center;` no use again.

```js
let $slides, interval, $selectors, $btns, currentIndex, nextIndex;

let cycle = index => {
  let $currentSlide, $nextSlide, $currentSelector, $nextSelector;

  nextIndex = index !== undefined ? index : nextIndex;

  $currentSlide = $($slides.get(currentIndex));
  $currentSelector = $($selectors.get(currentIndex));

  $nextSlide = $($slides.get(nextIndex));
  $nextSelector = $($selectors.get(nextIndex));

  $currentSlide.removeClass("active").css("z-index", "0");

  $nextSlide.addClass("active").css("z-index", "1");

  $currentSelector.removeClass("current");
  $nextSelector.addClass("current");

  currentIndex = index !== undefined ?
    nextIndex :
    currentIndex < $slides.length - 1 ?
    currentIndex + 1 :
    0;

  nextIndex = currentIndex + 1 < $slides.length ? currentIndex + 1 : 0;
};

$(() => {
  currentIndex = 0;
  nextIndex = 1;

  $slides = $(".slide");
  $selectors = $(".selector");
  $btns = $(".btn");

  $slides.first().addClass("active");
  $selectors.first().addClass("current");

  interval = window.setInterval(cycle, 6000);

  $selectors.on("click", e => {
    let target = $selectors.index(e.target);
    if (target !== currentIndex) {
      window.clearInterval(interval);
      cycle(target);
      interval = window.setInterval(cycle, 6000);
    }
  });

  $btns.on("click", e => {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("prev")) {
      let target = currentIndex > 0 ? currentIndex - 1 : $slides.length - 1;
      cycle(target);
    } else if ($(e.target).hasClass("next")) {
      cycle();
    }
    interval = window.setInterval(cycle, 6000);
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: -40%;
}

#slides .slide .slide-partial {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

#slides .slide .slide-partial img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

#slides .slide .slide-left {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

#slides .slide .slide-left img {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -o-object-position: 100% 50%;
  object-position: 100% 50%;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

#slides .slide.active .slide-partial,
#slides .slide.active .slide-partial img {
  transform: translateX(0);
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

#slide-select {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 100;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-family: "Reem Kufi", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: white;
}

#slide-select li {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

#slide-select li.prev:hover {
  transform: translateX(-2px);
}

#slide-select li.next:hover {
  transform: translateX(2px);
}

#slide-select .selector {
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#slide-select .selector.current {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="mode">
  <div id="container">
    <ul id="slides">
      <li class="slide">
        <div class="slide-partial slide-left"><img src="1.jpg" /></div>

      </li>
      <li class="slide">
        <div class="slide-partial slide-left"><img src="1.jpg" /></div>

      </li>
      <li class="slide">
        <div class="slide-partial slide-left"><img src="1.jpg" /></div>

      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="slide-select">
      <li class="btn prev">
        <</li>
          <li class="selector"></li>
          <li class="selector"></li>
          <li class="selector"></li>
          <li class="btn next">></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Output am getting,**

> Image slide with partially left floating

**I tried,**

```
display: inline-block;
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
/* result: no use /*
```

**What do I need the output to be,**

> proper centered image slide

---

> If possible please explain with a solution.

---

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` works only if you specify fixed width that is smaller than 100%.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to place something dead center is to use display: grid; and place-items: center; this will set all items on the grid to the center given the div has a specific with and height.

You also need to remove all styles from the li and ul, they have maring that can change the position of the elements inside